# Why is this object being finalized while still being used?

Tags: c#, active-directory, garbage-collection

I am trying to fetch a list of AD users using a `DirectorySearcher`:

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.com"))
using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
{
    // Setup the query...
    search.PageSize = 1000;

    using (SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll())
    {
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            // Read the results and insert in a list
        }
    }
}
```

This query can take up to a minute so I'm running in a thread from the thread pool (`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`). The query works fine and I get the correct results.

However, if I close the application while the query is running, I systematically get this MDA: `RaceOnRCWCleanup was detected`. Indeed, my thread is still running and is waiting for the enumeration to continue:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.DirectoryServices.dll!System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext() + 0x4a bytes
MyApp.exe!MyApp.ActiveDirectory.FetchAllUsers() Line 125 + 0x4dd bytes
```

At the same time, the finalizer thread is finalizing an instance of `DirectoryEntry`:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.__ComObject.ReleaseSelf() + 0x5 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object o) + 0x84 bytes 
System.DirectoryServices.dll!System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Unbind() + 0x27 bytes  
System.DirectoryServices.dll!System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Dispose(bool disposing) + 0x29 bytes   
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize() + 0x1b bytes
```

I can verify (through `Make Object ID` in Visual Studio) that the `DirectoryEntry` being finalized is the internal instance used by `SearchResultCollection`.

- Why is this `DirectoryEntry` being finalized while still being used?
- Does the finalizer know that this is a background thread that's going to exit and does it consider objects reachable only from that thread as being finalizable?
- Can I do something about it? Waiting for the query to finish before exiting the application is not acceptable.

### Update 1

Tried adding `GC.KeepAlive(results)` after the `foreach`. Also tried doing a GC.KeepAlive() on the internal `DirectoryEntry` in the `results` by first getting it through reflection. No luck: the entry is still being finalized...

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.com"))
using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
{
    using (SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll())
    {
        var rootEntryField = typeof(SearchResultCollection).GetField("rootEntry", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var rootEntry = rootEntryField.GetValue(results);

        foreach (SearchResult result in results) // Callstack is here when entry is finalized
        {
            // Do something
        }

        GC.KeepAlive(results);
        GC.KeepAlive(rootEntry); // This is the entry being finalized
   }

   GC.KeepAlive(search);
   GC.KeepAlive(entry);
}
```

A weird detail that I noticed is that, sometimes, the `SearchResultCollection` is also already disposed when I hit the MDA. I assume it was disposed through finalization because I clearly have not called `Dispose()` yet. In that case, it seems to me like the GC cannot finalize the object because I clearly need it later to dispose it...

### Update 2

I made a simple test to determine whether the GC can collect/finalize objects from a background thread when the application closes while the thread is seemingly still running. Consider this code running in a background thread:

```
using (new MyFinalizableType())
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
}
```

If you close the application while still in the using block, **you can verify that `~MyFinalizableType()` is called when the thread is still active** (you can see it and its callstack in the Threads window).

So, in conclusion, it seems that **the GC does consider those objects as collectable** and, in this case, there's nothing to be done to prevent the `RaceOnRCWCleanup` MDA.

Note that you can `GC.SuppressFinalize` the problematic objects but then the COM references would leak since the `Dispose()` method will never be called on the objects. AFAIK COM references cannot be reclaimed when a process exits unlike kernel objects/handles.

Comment: Well, it is a bug.  Caused by DirectoryEntry.Unbind(), it calls Marshal.ReleaseComObject().  Very naughty in general, it becomes a serious bug when the finalizer calls Unbind() and ReleaseComObject is called for a COM object that was already finalized.  You can't fix the bug, this is framework code.  The odds that MDA guessed right and your program is going to crash with an AccessViolationException is not high, this happens at program shutdown.  So either ignore it by turning the MDA off or feel better about it by making sure that the thread ended before you quit.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck with ignoring the MDA.. but that still doesn't explain why the object gets finalized in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why the `DirectoryEntry` object is no longer considered reachable. I doubt that the finalizer treats variables in background threads differently.

My best guess is that it's because it got disconnected somehow via the interop COM-wrapping process, i.e. it's technically reachable but only through a wrapper that's opaque to the GC.

You should be able to address the race condition by adding `GC.KeepAlive(entry);` after the `foreach` loop. That will ensure that the reference stored in `entry` is considered reachable until that statement (otherwise, the JIT compiler is allowed to optimize out the variable and cause the object to become unreachable earlier).

Comment: Adding ```GC.KeepAlive(entry)``` after the ```foreach``` does not change anything.. Note that I have to get the entry using the private field ```SearchResultCollection.rootEntry``` through reflection as it keeps its own copy.

Comment: Did you try `GC.KeepAlive(search)` instead (or in addition)? I know you wrote "does not change anything", but the difference in the stack trace between the `entry` object getting finalized and the `search` object getting finalized is subtle and would be easy to overlook. (I'm reasonably confident that the GC isn't trying to finalize a reachable object, so whatever the solution is, it will come down to ensuring the object is known to the GC as reachable).

Comment: It's always the entry being finalized. Updated the question to show the ```GC.KeepAlive``` attempts.

Answer (score 0):

An object can be finalized as soon as it will never again be accessed by executable code.  It is possible to meet that condition while in the middle of the execution of an instance method of the object being finalized.  If the method is called from the only accessible reference to the object, the caller never accesses the variable again before it goes out of scope, and the method's execution will not access the `this` variable (implicitly or explicitly) before the completion of the method then that object is eligible for finalization.  (This, among other reasons, is why why dealing with finalization is hard.)

The fact that the code is in a thread pool/background thread isn't relevant here.

[Here](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/10/construction-destruction/) is a blog post on the subject for some further reading.